# How to fix ceiling/wall joint after popcorn texture removal

Tags: drywall, paint, drywall-mud

Removed the popcorn, and the joints are in bad shape now. Guessing from the mud residue when it was scraped.[image] enter image description here

[image]

Comment: If you need to submit a pic zoomed in for us to see the issue, I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: Why does the surface still look textured ?

Comment: @RohitGupta it doesn't.  You can see at the corner the texture (what there is) is different.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t actually see what’s going on in your pictures, but I don’t need to.

Ceilings that get a popcorn finish have been casually (to say the least) taped and skimmed.

What you need to do (assuming you want a visually pleasing flat ceiling) is skim out further from the tape joints. This will also have the benefit of filling any dings/voids.

There are plenty of tutorials on youtube, but here are my tips:

- use topping mud as it is easier to sand
- less is better… build gradually in multiple coats, rather than trying to glop it all on in one
- if you have high standards/ low patience, and/or the light hits the ceiling at a low angle (sunset, sunup), you might consider calling a pro. Drywall is a skill that takes time to learn